# Rewriting output of GET form

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I don't know how to rewrite output of my GET form, I am working on this page http://ibarman.cz/koktejly. When you select some test coctail, it works, but when you are in detail of coctail and search coctail, it gives you http://ibarman.cz/koktejly/Meloun+vodka?code=Creme+de+le+creme&hledat= and I want just want /koktejly/Creme+de+le+creme

My .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex c.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^koktejly/([^/]*)$ /test/c.php?code=$1&hledat= [L]
RewriteRule ^koktejly$ /test/c.php [L]
RewriteRule ^koktejly-stranka([^_]*)$ /test/c.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /test/c.php?code=$1&hledat=
```